# Silverlight marshalling DLLs and cross platform / cross browser?

Tags: .net, silverlight

We have a DLL that is written in C , I beleive. Currently, we have a windows application that allows a user to select some files and then pass the files (an array of file names from the file system) to the DLL to be processed. We would like to have the application be an add-in to IE or FireFox , run on a MAC or PC, and sill allow us to marshal the DLL. Would silverlight work for this situation or will the DLL need to be coded for other platforms.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you won't be able to use silverlight for this.  Simply because of the [security model](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2007/05/09/the-silverlight-security-model.aspx).  You can do the file-picker thing no problem from silverlight, but I am pretty sure you can not P/Invoke.

[see this article on Dr. Dobbs](http://www.ddj.com/security/206902613?pgno=3)